# Finding Standard deviations of rows on multiple colums on R

Tags: r, standard-deviation

I just started processing my data using R. I would like to know how I can find the standard deviation of rows on multiple columns on a data1.data

|  C1.  | C2.  | C3.  | C4..  | SD |

|------|------|-----|------|

| 123 | 234 | 456 | 321 |

| 342 | 334 | 123 | 432 |

| 257 | 987 | 543 | 456 |

so, I've been trying to use R for this,
I've already tried

```
C_sd <- apply(data1.data[, c(1,4)],1,sd)
```

I get incorrect SD values from this.

I've also tried using rowSds()

```
dataC.data <- data1.data[,1:4]
sdC <- rowSds(dataC.data)
```

and I get this

> Error in rowVars(x, ...) : Argument 'x' must be a matrix or a vector.

Comment: Usually when people claim that `sd` or `var` give them "wrong" answers, it's because they haven't read the documentation which points out that they use `n - 1` as a divisor, while some other systems use `n` by default. `n - 1` yields an unbiased estimate.

Comment: Try str(data1.data[, 1:4]) to see if it is matrix or data frame. The function rowSds expects a vector or a matrix as input.

Comment: Thanks, It was a data frame and I converted it to a matrix using

data.matrix(data1.data, rownames.force = NA)

and now rowSds() works